# Understanding instance variable and property in Objective-C 2.0

Tags: objective-c

My development environment:

> Xcode 4.6.2
>
> non-Automatic Reference Counting

For example, suppose we have a view controller called `CertainViewController`, where a `NSArray *` typed property called `listData` has been declared, with attributes `retain` and `nonatomic`. `listData` is to be loaded to a table view. I would do it like this:

```
// CertainViewController.h
@interface CertainViewController : UIViewController
{
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *listData;

// CertainViewController.m
@implementation CertainViewController

@synthesize listData;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    
    // someValue is ready
    self.listData = someValue;
    // Release someValue
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    self.listData = nil;
}
```

While some other developers would explicitly specify the instance variable `_listData` for property `listData` and do it like this:

```
// CertainViewController.h
@interface CertainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSArray *_listData;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *listData;

// CertainViewController.m
@implementation CertainViewController

@synthesize listData = _listData;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    
    // someValue is ready
    self.listData = someValue;
    // Release someValue
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [_listData release];
}
```

Are the above two implementations totally equivalent? Or any tiny differences? The explicit appointing instance variable as `_listData` just mean to be use `[_listData release];`?

Any hint is welcome and thank you for help :D

Comment: In dealloc method you should (it is recommended) after release assign _listData = nil;

Comment: And of course don't forget to call [super dealloc];

Answer (score 2):

They're essentially the same, but if you want to know the exact difference, check out the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Answer (score 2):

With the latest clang compiler you don't need to declare the instance variable, the compiler does it for you automatically.

Actually you don't even need to declare `@synthesize` anymore either. As soon as you declare your `@property`, the compiler will generate the getter, setter and the instance variable like if you had written:

```
@synthesize listData = _listData;
```

Comment: unless your code needs to run in 32 bit Mac land then you still need your backing iVar.

Comment: You might occasionally still want to declare an instance variable in the header - to allow access in a sub-class or category, for example.

Comment: @JasperBlues Yes indeed. I figured I'd provide the simplest answer that covers most cases related to declaring a `@property`

Comment: Yup, sounds good. . . I think those edge cases are interesting - and can come in handy for certain things.